# SELECT command denied to user 'incoktys_rig_vtu_admin'@'localhost' for table 'users' in /home/incoktys/public_html/vtu/login.php:98

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, cpanel

I've a website hosted through namecheap and using cpanel, I've been getting this error in the error log file, which prevents a MySQL action, I've granted privileges to the user but the problem remains. How can I resolve this?

This is what the error looks like:

> SELECT command denied to user 'incoktys_rig_vtu_admin'@'localhost' for
> table 'users' in /home/incoktys/public_html/vtu/login.php:98

Comment: grant privilege then reboot the server

Comment: First show current privilege of your user with : SHOW GRANTS FOR 'incoktys_rig_vtu_admin'@'localhost';

After if it's ok do not forget to run the command : FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it,
the solution is to prepend then db user name with the name of the db table in every MySQL query like this:

```
`username`.`tablename`
```